# cannot implicitly convert type int to (namespace.model.class) type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables service and Appointments I'm trying to insert serviceId to Appointments table, but serviceId type (Int) and appointments.service.Id (namespace.model.class) so the error is"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'namespace.model.class'

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 ...
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         appointments = new Appointments()
         {
             service = appointments.service.Id,
         };

         db.Appointments.Add(appointments);
         db.SaveChanges();
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

Comment: Your `Appointments` entity should have a `ServiceId` foreign key (in addition to the full entity relationship `Service`). Assign the ServiceId.

Comment: @StuartLC yes Appointments has ServiceId  as a foreign key, Appointments.cs  `public virtual Services service { get; set; }`

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do - `appointments` must already exist in order for you to be able to reference `appointments.service.id`, and then you are trying to assign the foreign key `serviceId` to something which should already be there, if you've already retrieved appointment from the database. In which case, you likely won't be able to `Add` the same Appointment to the table again.

Comment: Can you give more detail about your Appintmant class and your service class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign object to an id which is type of int. If you have foreign key in your `Appointments` class like `ServiceId` assign to it.

```
appointments = new Appointments()
         {
             serviceid = appointments.service.Id,
         };
```

Or if you dont have that property then you should do

```
appointments = new Appointments()
         {
             service = appointments.service,
         };
```

But your `appointment.service` shouldnt be null.